# How to use Parcelable in Java Code

Tags: java, android, module, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-module project in Android Studio and define my business objects (the POJO objects I want to work with in the ui) in a pure java module (called "application"). The final product will be an Android App which connects to a server.

My app structure is the following (I have a multi-layer architecture whereas each layer represents a module):

```
 Project
 - presentation (android ui)
 - application (logic / mapping DTO <--> Business Objects (POJOs))
 - data (mapping JSON <--> Data Transfer Object (DTO))
 - transport (network communication)
```

The lower 3 modules are pure java / only the first one is an Android module.

Now my question is:
How can I still use Android's Parcelable for the mentioned POJOs (in a pure java module). Is there a gradle dependency for that? I didn't find anything until now so it would appreciate some useful hints.

I wouldn't like to use Serializable and would prefer not to change the module to an Android module.

UPDATE: I tried to just implement Parcelable in the java module (which does work without any problem, but it doesn't recognize android.os.Parcelable when building. So I'm back to the very beginning of my question.

UPDATE II: Answers like try Parceler or anything like that don't work as android.os.Parcelable is not recognized in the module. I'm not looking for answers how to implement Parcelable but how to be able to use Parcelable in pure Java. Thanks.

SOLUTION: See below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O.K., it now is working. I finally realized that it is impossible to run pure java modules inside an Android Application and that you always have to apply the android library plugin instead of the java plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

I also had to add a Manifest.xml and add the following to the build.gradle of the java modules:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```

Comment: it is _not_ impossible to run pure java modules in an android application. however if you want to access something like `Parcelable` which is from android.os, then you must use `'com.android.library'` plugin

Comment: That's not true! you can always embed a pure java module in android apps.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend against using `Parcelable`. And I've used it a lot. Avoid it if you are not going to use IPC in Android. If you're not going to pass these objects between Android processes, you don't need to implement `Parcelable`.

If you want to pass objects between Android processes, then `Parcelable` is a must. You should look into [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html). Note that the classes still have to implement `Parcelable`, even if you use AIDL.

You don't need any special dependency, the Android SDK is enough.

EDIT:

I know the linked documentation says that *"If you do not need to perform concurrent IPC across different applications, you should create your interface by implementing a Binder or, if you want to perform IPC, but do not need to handle multithreading, implement your interface using a Messenger"*. In my experience, I disagree with this recommendation. Using bound services and `Messenger` was a painful path full of hidden traps. AIDL is much easier and straightforward to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but I need to use the POJOs in my Android module and therefore also pass them between Android processes. AIDL seems to be a bit to much overhead for what I'm trying to do. Especially as it is the first time I would use it...

Comment: No, AIDL is actually the best way to use `Parcelable`. It's **much** easier and also supports multi-threading. If you don't want to use AIDL, you need to implement the IPC yourself.

Comment: Glad to help, just one last note to make sure I explained the issue clearly: AIDL will take care of transporting the `Parcelable` object from one process to the other, but if you don't use it (which is what I personally did at first and now I rewrote it to use AIDL instead) you need to implement this transport by yourself (I used binders and Messenger in my obsolete implementation).

Comment: @Andev I don't care about the votes. I've been working with Android IPC for 3 years now. I just want you to understand that, really, you should use AIDL. I was like you, reticent to use it, but the benefits are huge and it is easy to use. Believe me, writing your own IPC will only give 3 things: threading problems, headaches, and slowness. Of course you can also learn this by yourself like I did :) **Note that the classes still have to implement Parcelable, even if you use AIDL**.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand quite well what you are trying to archive, but you can use gson for easily communication between android processes and even ws.
 Just convert your object to json using gson (its automatized based on your pojo) and convert from json to object in the other side.

Comment: Your answer is lacking important details. How will you send the JSON without implementing `Parcelable`? How you will open a communication channel between 2 Android processes?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an easy way to wrap POJOs as `Parcelable`s then try out [Parceler](http://parceler.org).  Parceler is an annotation processor that generates `Parcelable`s based on the fields of your POJO model classes.

To have Parceler generate `Parcelable`s for your pure-java library, use the `@ParcelClass` annotation in your Android-specific source (presentation?) to direct Parceler which POJOs to use as a model.

From Parceler's generated `Parcelable` output, you can either use the generated classes directly, or by the `Parcels.wrap()` and `Parcels.unwrap()` utility class before and after serializing your data to a `Bundle`.